# type3 compensator's Vref

Tags: buck

I'm not sure if my intuition is a correct thing.

[image]

This is type 3 compensator included in feedback of buck converter.

The problem is, that I cannot fully understand how Vref works.

At first, I understood like that in steady state, which means there's no variations, capacitors are being open circuits, so there's so negative feedback at this compensator.

So $$ V_{-} = V_{o} \beta $$
where $$ \beta = R_{4}/[R_{1} + R_{4}] $$

If the reference voltage is ground, that compensator is saturated, and it's a problem.

So, We intentionally give the reference voltage that equals to V-, and DC output will be ground.

After that, if output variates, the compensator will amplify the variation.

But it has a problem too, that Ve is input voltage of amplifier that makes PULSE signal, so

if we make Ve zero upon my intuitions, it cannot operate as PWM mode.

So I think I'm making mistakes, or missing something. Please help..

Comment: You are trying to make sense of one fractional part of a signal processing circuit when there is overall negative feedback and you are making assumptions that are probably irrelevant in the whole scheme of things. Neither have you attributed the diagram and this is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is the whole point of the control system: you amplify the dc error between the target (or an image of it via resistors \$R_1\$ and \$R_4\$) to meet the regulation point. The difference epsilon or \$\epsilon\$ is amplified by the op-amp open-loop gain and seen as the dc bias on its output driving the power stage. In the below example, the drive is 1 V which via the pulse-width modulator induces a duty ratio of 51%. It is slightly more than 50% to compensate for the drop in the inductor ohmic loss. It would even be larger if you would include the MOSFET \$r_{DS(on}\$:

[image]

In the below example, the *static* error between the wanted scaled-down 5-V output and the 2.5-V reference voltage is 34 µV and amplified by the op-amp gain which exhibits an open-loop gain of 30000. If this open-loop gain would theoretically be infinite, the system would have a zero static error.

You are correct in your remarks that the op-amp could rail up or down in some cases. For instance during the start-up sequence, when \$V_{out}\$ is rising and far from the target: the op-amp asks for the maximum power and drives the duty ratio to the maximum value by hitting its upper rail. During a sudden load release also, as the output can potentially overshoot. In this case, the op-amp will rail down considering the large static error and recovers a few moments later when \$V_{out}\$ returns to its steady-state value.